# How to figure out which transistor amplifies the signal?

Tags: transistors, amplifier

Suppose I have the following circuit:
[image]

How can I determine which transistor amplifies the signal and which transistor is just a simple resistor? Also if is a resistor how can I determine it's resistence?

Comment: it looks like an AC coupled power driver/buffer... Q3 and Q4 make a darlington current source, and Q5 acts as a (less powerful) current sink, making Q1 and Q2 as the input amplifier and feedback stage.. I think!

Comment: @KyranF Not quite; it's a differential amplifier. Q3 is an emitter-follower amplifier, and Q4 and Q5 an AB- class output driver. The negative differential input is hooked up to the output via a voltage divider to provide a fixed gain.

Comment: @NickJohnson ah, so that's the feedback influence from Q2 - it's a negative feedback?

Comment: @KyranF Yup, though the feedback's _to_ Q2.

Comment: @NickJohnson No, Q3 is not an emitter follower, its emitter is connected to the supply rail. Q4/5 can be considered emitter followers if you like, but better to look at them as a push-pull pair in class AB.

Comment: @jippie Sure, because it's a PNP. What would you prefer to call it? A collector-follower, I guess?

Comment: @NickJohnson how about common emitter? To the best of my knowledge there is no such thing as a collector follower. Collector has a high output impedance whereas emitter has a low output impedance. Collector is good as a current source, emitter is good as a voltage source (follower).

Comment: @NickJohnson Q3 being a PNP has utterly nothing to do with it being an emitter follower or not. An emitter follower is a sub-unity voltage gain stage with a current gain and a power gain and output taken from the emitter. It's a 'follower" because the Vout follows Vin with an offset (to a first approximation). When output is taken from the collector (PNP or NPN)you get voltage gain (or should), current gain and power gain (usually). Nothing "follows" anything in anything like the strict or usual senses of the term.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon You're absolutely right, of course; I should have said it's a common-collector(?) amplifier. I'm still reading TAoE. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None on them are "simple resistors". If they were then you'd find a resistor there instead of a transistor.
Every transistor in that circuit is in some way involved in amplifying the signal (although there could be some argument about Q2, since that one is in the feedback loop).
No sane circuit designer is going to use a transistor to do the job of a simple resistor.

Comment: but when i calculate the gain I should consider every transistor in this circuit?

Comment: If you assume that the open-loop gain of the circuit is "large enough" then all you need to know is the ratio of the negative feedback resistors R7 & R8. Imagine you don't see all those transistors but an opamp instead - negative feedback sets the gain at 1+Rx/Ry.

Comment: Following on brhans comment, the open-loop gain is (gm1R3)*(gm3R6).  Whether this is "large enough" depends on your accuracy requirements.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

I'll try to discuss the circuit without going too much into all the details, cutting a few corners here and there to make it easier to understand rather than being 100% accurate. Important to realize is that amplification actually consists of two things:

- voltage gain
- current gain (often forgotten)

I think the black magic is really in the DC bias of the whole circuit, I won't discuss that as it requires a fair amount more understanding of how transistors work and it highly depends on the exact values of the transistors and resistors which haven't been given in the original post.

Your circuit can be split into three parts:

1. Input stage is made up from Q1, Q2, R3..R5
2. Class AB bias D1, D2 and Q3
3. Output stage, consisting of Q4 and Q5

Let's work back from the output stage to the input, right to left in the circuit diagram.

## Output stage Q4, Q5

When you look into the emitter of Q4 or Q5 from the output, you'll see what seems to be a low resistance (or better low impedance) from load perspective. These transistors won't amplify the voltage, as a matter of fact they slightly attenuate the voltage swing with regard to their base voltages. They do however substantially increase the current that can be drawn from them (current gain). Hence this is what enables the amplifier to drive a low impedance load like a speaker.

## Class AB bias

For the output stage to operate in class AB, and with that improve sound quality, it is important that the voltage offset introduced by the output transistors Q4/Q5 is compensated. This is what the two diodes are used for. Assume for sake of argument that the voltage across D1, D2 doesn't change with the input signal and is identical to the base-to-emitter voltage drop in the transistors Q4 and Q5. This ensures that both transistors are in (or at least very close to) their active region and every change in voltage across R6 is fed to Q5 and Q4. If you like you can imagine D1 and D2 as a constant voltage source.

Q3 can be viewed as a current source, controlled by the input signal. Because the collector current changes with the input signal, the voltage across R6 will vary with the Q3 transistor current and thus with the input signal. The varying voltage across R6 is then 'copied' to Q5 emitter and with a 1.4V offset (introduced by the two diodes) to Q4 emitter.

## Input stage

Q1 and Q2 are configured as a differential amplifier. They amplify the voltage difference observed between base/Q1 and base/Q2. Base/Q1 is clearly controlled by the input voltage and base/Q2 is controlled by the output signal. The voltage gain of the whole circuit will be approximately R7/(R7+R8).

Q1/R3 and Q3/R6(!) will be the components that take the majority of the open loop voltage gain of the whole circuit. The open loop voltage gain would be the gain of the circuit without the feed back through R8.

Comment: How do people figure out this kind of circuits...I am really more the digital guy ;) But well, learning every day...

Comment: @Rev1.0 /me shrugs. I look at the circuit and I see the electrons move.

Comment: @Rev1.0 Buy and read The Art of Electronics, 3rd ed, especially chapter 2 on BJTs. A week of reading it has already turned "analog black magic" into circuits I recognise on sight.

Comment: @Rev1.0 the way analog guys figure out circuits is to realize that the vast majority of circuits are built using a relatively small number of building blocks.  An experienced analog designer will look at your circuit and immediately say "OK, there's a resistively loaded diff pair followed by a textbook class AB output stage".  Analog design is all about learning the core circuit patterns really well so you can mix and match them and figure out what is going on.  It's rare an analog designer sees (or designs) a truly new circuit configuration.

Comment: @NickJohnson The book should be called 'the *Black Magic* Art of Electronics'

Comment: @Rev1.0 You soak in it long enough and it's like riding  a bicycle. Sometimes you fall off :-). All the elements of that circuit have been around since the 1st few years of transistors existing, and in revised form since before then. The cct is essentially a simplified "op amp" and early ones would hardly have had more than that in them. Even the classic olde LM324, which came along long after the party started, looks suspiciously like a superset of that cct. [LM324 description](http://www.usmicrowaves.com/opamps/LM324.htm) & [internal circuitry](http://www.usmicrowaves.com/opamps/324.gif)

Comment: @NickJohnson: Its totally on my list. I wanted to buy it 2 years ago but I heard rumor of a 3rd edition. With the 2nd edition being 20 years old I decided to wait for it. I did not realize it came out this March :)

Comment: @crgrace: No question its a matter of experience. My initial comment was more aiming at the point how to come up with complex designs in the first place instead of how to understand the basic functions of an existing circuit. Maybe my phrasing was off, English is not my first language.

Comment: @Rev1.0 I read an anecdote once, I believe it was about Bob Widlar, but can't find it right now. Anyways, the story was about how two pioneers in transistor integrated circuits were challenging each other to build a current mirror with as few as possible transistors with the best symmetry in currents. Nice story how the circuit evolved from a back of envelope drawing to an actual circuit that is probably still found in integrated circuits today. Thought one of the guys was Widlar, maybe someone remembers more details or has the link to the story.